# Android Air - How to keep application alive during sleep

Tags: android, air

If it is possible to keep an Air for Android application alive during sleep, how can it be done? I know how to prevent sleep and lock but this course is not preferable to some users.

**Update**

The reason in this case is to keep the video streaming from the phone to a server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are talking about is preventing Screen Dimming for AIR apps. That is possible using the following:

NativeApplication.nativeapplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE

This overrides the default behaviour and screen never times out until the AIR app is in foreground. To take the mode back to normal you can set the property back to SystemIdleMode.NORMAL. In addition to this code, you will have to specify two permissions in your app.xml for AIR app, which are:

android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD

But as Emmanuel mentioned above, this would definitely mean that your battery will be consumed much faster. However, it could be useful in apps where Video is playing and you don't want the screen to dim.

Hope this helps.
Mohit

Comment: This solution works fine to keep the app alive but after a while the network connection dies, sadly. :/

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to keep it alive? If the user no longer looks at his phone, why consume the CPU/RAM/battery?

If you want to do something in the background at regular intervals you could use an Alarm. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

This lets you start the alarm even if the phone is sleeping.

If you want to do other kinds of background processing, you could use a Service running in the Foreground. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29

This doesn't 100% guarantee that the service will always stay up and running though, e.g. when the phone runs low on memory.

I hope this is helpful...

Emmanuel